# One check mark per section

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, model-view-controller

I try to only show one check mark per section. So when the user selects a row in a section the last selected row in this row should be deselected and the new row selected with a checkmark. I want to approach this very dynamic and generic since there is going to be an dynamic number of sections.

What I have so far is the following:

```
if(self.product ? subMenus.group.selectedRow  : subMenusInProductCart.group.selectedRow)
    {
        UITableViewCell *uncheckCell;

        if (self.product) {

            uncheckCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:subMenus.group.selectedRow.integerValue inSection:indexPath.section]];

            if (uncheckCell.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark) {

                SubMenus *subMenu = [self.indexPathController.dataModel itemAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:subMenus.group.selectedRow.integerValue inSection:indexPath.section]];

                subMenu.selected = @(NO);


                if (subMenus.price.floatValue > 0) {

                    self.totalPrice = [self subtractSubMenuPrice:subMenus.price.floatValue fromProductPrice:self.totalPrice];

                }

            }




        }else if (self.cartProduct) {

            uncheckCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:subMenusInProductCart.group.selectedRow.integerValue inSection:indexPath.section]];

            if (uncheckCell.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark) {


                SubMenuProductCart *subMenuProductCart = [self.indexPathController.dataModel itemAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:subMenus.group.selectedRow.integerValue inSection:indexPath.section]];
                subMenuProductCart.selected = @(NO);

                if (subMenuProductCart.subMenu.price.floatValue > 0) {
                    self.totalPrice = [self subtractSubMenuPrice:subMenuProductCart.subMenu.price.floatValue fromProductPrice:self.totalPrice];
                }


            }




        }

        uncheckCell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;



    }

    if ([subMenus.group.selectedRow isEqualToNumber:@(indexPath.row)])
    {

        if (self.product) {

            subMenus.selected = @(NO);

            subMenus.group.selectedRow = nil;


            if (subMenus.price.floatValue > 0) {


                self.totalPrice = [self subtractSubMenuPrice:subMenus.price.floatValue fromProductPrice:self.totalPrice];

            }

        }

    }else {

        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;

        if (self.product) {

            subMenus.selected = @(YES);

            subMenus.group.selectedRow = @(indexPath.row);


            if (subMenus.price.floatValue > 0) {
                self.totalPrice = [self addSubMenuPrice:subMenus.price.floatValue toProductPrice:self.totalPrice];
            }


        }else if (self.cartProduct) {

            subMenusInProductCart.selected = @(YES);

            subMenusInProductCart.group.selectedRow = @(indexPath.row);

            if (subMenusInProductCart.subMenu.price.floatValue > 0) {
                self.totalPrice = [self addSubMenuPrice:subMenusInProductCart.subMenu.price.floatValue toProductPrice:self.totalPrice];
            }

        }


    }
```

The above code is working, but I think their must be a better solution to this, than saving the selected row in Core Data? Please bear in mind that the selected state is going to be manipulated later, since the user can change his or her's selection (shopping cart). Currently the selected object (row) is passed to another object (a relationship object) with an independent selected row property.

In order to illustrate my setup:

[image]

So is there a better and more generic way to handle this one selection per section with Core Data objects instead of saving the selected row in with the NSMangedObject, which dosen't seems so MVC'ish?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `selectedRow` is a meaningful part of your data model I see no problem with saving the selected state in Core Data. I am not sure what the relationship between the `selected` and `selectedRow` attribute is, but ideally you would do with only one of these.